# How to draw a static circle on a UISlider?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider, cgrect, uicontrol

I'm trying to render a few small circles based on times of an event, I want it to look like this, the alert timings are defined before the view loads so it doesn't need to be dynamic but have no idea how to go about it, any advice / code would be great, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have plenty of open source projects that cover your needs.
Look at these links:
http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/how-we-created-custom-slider-marks-ios
http://www.raywenderlich.com/36288/how-to-make-a-custom-control
http://www.alexanderbatalov.com/journal/2015/2/20/how-to-implement-custom-uislider-in-swift

In connection to drawing circle you could simple use this code on UIView and after that add this to the slider

```
func initializeCircle() {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.width/2
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
}
```